# I can not subscribe on mergeMap observable in angular 13

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I want to implement a connexion senario based on Roles in angular. When the user click on CONNEXION button after filling in the form ( username - password), two API urls are called to serve the same connexion and I'm using angular 13 for the frontend. In the backend I have the two endpoints ( ressources request url ) to serve the connexion process. The first ressource

> this.http.post(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/users/login`,
> data, Option)

provides the token for authentication and the second ressource

> this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/prsnls`,
> this.userId)

has to find the user's role based on the userId provided by the firt API call from the token. Everything works fine when testing with postman. But I'm struggling to implement the connexion process in the frontend with angular and this is what I have done so far:

//LOGIN METHOD THAT CALLS THE 2 API URLs

```
login(data){
      const Option ={ headers: new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json',"USER_CODE":data.USER_CODE})};
      this.http.post<any>(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/users/login`, data, Option)
      .pipe(
        map(value => value[0]))
      .subscribe( value => {
        this.userId = value.result.userId;
        this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/prsnls`, this.userId)
        .subscribe( user => {
          this.user = user;
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
              this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
              return user;
        });
      })
    }
```

//THE ONSUBMIT ACTION WHEN THE BUTTON IS PRESSED

```
onSubmit(){
    const data = this.loginForm.getRawValue();
    this.submitted = true;
    localStorage.setItem('USER_CODE',data.USER_CODE);
    this.loading = true;
    this.isLoading = true;
    of(null)
      .pipe(
        delay(2000),
        first()
      )
      .subscribe(() => {

        this.isLoading = false;
        this.authService.login(data).subscribe(
            (res:any)=>{
              if (res.code==200){
                  localStorage.setItem('token',res.result.token);
                  localStorage.setItem("infos", JSON.stringify(res.result.roleIds));
                  localStorage.setItem("prsl", res.result.userId);
                  //this.getUserInfos(res.result.userId);
                  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
              }

              this.rMessage = '';

            },
              error => {
                  this.rMessage = 'bError';
                  this.loading = false;
              }
          );
      });


  }
```

The problem is that the editor says the '**subscribe()**' property does not exist on type void inside the onsubmit() function on the line `this.authService.login(data).subscribe()` and I don't understand why I can't subscribe to that observable. I appreciate if anyone can help, because I don't know how to fix this and get the editor without errors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In TypeScript/JavaScript, functions without a return statement implicitly return void. Since `login(data)` doesn't have a return statement, trying to do anything with it's return value (for example, subscribing to it) will be an error.

Comment: 1st of all you are not returning anything,where return type `observable` is expected.Do you want to merge two api response and return from `login` ?

Comment: @MrkSef ok, but when I put return before the this.http.post<any> observable to return it, the outcome is the same

Comment: @Saptarsi yes, I want to merge the 2 api responses when the second one depends on the response from the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember: "your services return observables, you subscribe in components"

Each time you write "subscribe" in your service you're falling in a bad practice (*)

Well, you need return an observable based in another one, so you need use switchMap rxjs operator. switchMap is always in the way

```
observable1(data).pipe(switchMap(res=>{
   //here res is the response of the observable1(data)
   //you return another observable based in res
   return observable2(res) 
})
```

Your login

```
login(data){
      const Option ={ headers: new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json',"USER_CODE":data.USER_CODE})};
      
      //see that you "return" an observable
      return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/users/login`, data, Option)
      .pipe(
       switchMap(value=>{
          const userId=value[0].result.userId
          return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/prsnls`, userId)

       })
```

Now you can subscribe

```
onSubmit(){
    const data = this.loginForm.getRawValue();
    this.submitted = true;
    this.authService.login(data).subscribe(
            (res:any)=>{
              if (res.code==200){
                  localStorage.setItem('token',res.result.token);
                  localStorage.setItem("infos", JSON.stringify(res.result.roleIds));
                  localStorage.setItem("prsl", res.result.userId);
                  //this.getUserInfos(res.result.userId);
                  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
              }

              this.rMessage = '';

            },
              error => {
                  this.rMessage = 'bError';
                  this.loading = false;
              }
          );
      });
```

(*)well you can to have in your service some like

```
subject=new Subject<any>()
getData(){
   this.httpClient.get(...).subscribe(res=>{
       this.subject.next(res)
   })
}
```

And you subscribe to the "subject" and call to the function

```
this.authService.subject.subscribe(res=>{
   ...
})
this.authService.getData();
```

But it's for some "special cases"

**Update** Sometime, futhermore the data of the inner Observable we need also the data of the first observable we need use another rxjs operator `map`

We can do

```
   observable1(data).pipe(switchMap(respose1=>{
       return observable2(response1).pipe(map(response=>(
         {response1:response1,response2:response2}
       )))
    })
```

And we have an object with two properties: response1 and response2

Well we can map also using spread operator

```
   observable1(data).pipe(switchMap(respose1=>{
       return observable2(response1).pipe(map(response=>(
         {...response1,...response2}
       )))
    })
```

And we get an unique object with all the properties of response1 and response2

Comment: Thanks, I will make the changes and see the outcome.

Comment: I made the changes and it compiles successfully, but user can not login. I think it is because raw response return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/prsnls`, userId) was returned instead of return user. How can I return user after the return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/prsnls`, userId). The login worked when I used one single api call and I previously did : return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/users/login`, data, Option).pipe(map(user => {  return user }) . How can I return user within switchMap. Thanks

Comment: @HimmelsDJ, I update the answer adding the necesary if you need also the response of the outher observable (using map in the second observable). I wrote "in general" (not with your observables. I hope can help you). a [little stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kfuu8d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `Observable` from **login** method.

If you subscribe and return then will be returning `Subcription` type.So in-order to return `Observable` and manipulate result and do some stuff after response came you have to use `pipe`.

I changed your **login** method like below

```ts
  login(data): Observable<any> {
    const Option = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        USER_CODE: data.USER_CODE,
      }),
    };
    return this.http
      .post<any>('${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/users/login', data, Option)
      .pipe(
        map((value) => value[0]),
        tap((value) => (this.userId = value.result.userId)),
        switchMap((value) =>
          this.http
            .get<User>('${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/prsnls', this.userId)
            .pipe(
              tap((user:User) => {
                this.user = user;
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
              }),
              map((user) => ({ ...user, ...value }))
            )
        )
      );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes accordingly, but the editor complains on the second pipe() of the login() function saying that property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, arrayBuffer>'. And On "this.user = user;" it says "can not assign type 'unknown' to type '(id: any) => Observable<Object>' The type '{}' has no corresponding for signature '(id: any): Observable<Object>"

Comment: I have modified my code,check now

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I changed like below the error now is on last tap((user:User) => { this.user = user; ...} in vscode saying Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<User>' is not assignable to parameter type 'OperatorFunction<ArrayBuffer, User>'. The types 'source' and 'source' not compatible. When I remove the type User from 'user' and made it tap(user => { this.user = user ... } , error now appears on this.user = user saying " can not assign type 'ArrayBuffer' to '(id : any) => Observable<Object>'.type 'ArrayBuffer' has no corresponding for signature '(id: any): Observable<Object>"

Comment: `${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/prsnls` response and `this.user` response type same?

Comment: Yeah the response and this.user have same properties. I understand pretty much your approach but it's encontering Arraybuffer mismatching object issues. I will investigate a way to tackle that error. But adapting @Eiseo 's answer it compiled and  chrome debugging network show login 200 OK. Thank you very much for the technics I've learned.

Comment: `this.user = user` is it required as per your logic,otherwise you can ignore

Comment: if you have `User` type, then can do like this `http.get<User>`...modified my answer with this.If ti is possible then try once

Comment: Yeah that was it, it compiles now. Big thanks