# I can't pass header option to a GET request within switchMap observable in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm implementing a login system using based on two requests. The first request yields the userId, and the userId is passed to the second request to find the userRole, which provides authentication status and redirection to relevant dashboard.

From the API side, both requests take header options and body parameters. Additionally the second request takes the token provided by the first request. I'm able to pass header options to the first call and it's successful:

```
this.http.post<any>(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/users/login`, data, Option)
```

but the second call:

```
this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/prsnls`, userId, RoleOptions)
```

doesn't accept the header option `RoleOptions`. This is the code:

```
login(data){
      const Option ={ headers: new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json',"USER_CODE":data.USER_CODE})};
      
      //see that you "return" an observable
      return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/users/login`, data, Option)
      .pipe(
       switchMap(value=>{
          const userId = value[0].result.userId
          const currentToken = value[0].result.token
          const RoleOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                            'Authorization : 'Bearer' + currentToken, 
                            'USER_CODE':data.USER_CODE
                            )};
                          }
          return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrlUserSecurity}/prsnls`, userId, 
                           RoleOptions)

       }).pipe(map(user =>(
         { ...user}
       )))
```

But VS Code complains about the `RoleOptions` which is the third argument passed to the get request within the `switchMap` saying that only *"1 or 2 arguments are needed, but received 3"*. Why can't I pass header options to the GET request added to the body parameter passed to it?

Comment: Did you read the API docs? They tell you what the arguments to each method are - GET requests, unlike POSTs, don't (semantically, at least) have a body.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, but how do I then deal with such situation? I'm getting the data from backend and in postman, the get request required a token in authorization, a userId and the USER_CODE in the header option. How do I implement that?

Comment: We don't know. You haven't told us enough about the request you're trying to make. You seem to be trying to make the GET with the user ID as the _body_ of the request, which [doesn't really make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/q/978061/3001761) (although sadly that doesn't rule out it being what the API expects...). But again the API docs tell you how to use the methods - `get` expects a URL and, optionally, the options object (including headers, etc.). _"Why can't I pass header options to the GET request?"_ - you can, but it's not the third parameter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is the context described in a previous question about mapping multiple request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71958770/i-can-not-subscribe-on-mergemap-observable-in-angular-13

Comment: Please [edit] so that the relevant context and a minimal example (only the GET is relevant, no?) is in _this question_. The other one doesn't seem to show exactly what request you're trying to make either, though.

Comment: Again you _can_ pass the header options. You can't pass the _body_, because an XHR won't send a GET with a body (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70118101/3001761). The problem is with the API design, if that's actually what's needed.

Comment: Ok @jonrsharpe, everything is very clear to me now. I'm going to review the  api architecture. Thanks